# Understanding the inner workings of a programming language

Tags: parsing, programming-languages, lexer

Where would be a good place to start learning the inner workings of a programming language like C?
Would it be learning how a parser/lexer works?

Comment: Read the code: http://bellard.org/tcc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really. Parsing is only a small part of the complexity of a language, and not the most interesting part. Typing (for C, not such a big part either), optimization, code generation: those are the bulk of the compiler.

The first step is to know the language well. Get a book such as [*The C Programming Language* by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie (“K&R”)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_%28book%29). Do the exercises.

Then you may find it interesting to learn [how a compiler works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669/learning-to-write-a-compiler).

A good way of measuring your understanding of C is to read the
[standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). (This is not a tutorial!) See how much you understand. See if you understand why the standard does things the way it does.